# Sidekiq perform_async is not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, redis, mongoid, sidekiq

I'm creating Elasticsearch callbacks using Sidekiq. I started Redis and Sidekiq, and created an object in rails console but it seems like `perform_sync` is not firing. If I add `require 'sidekiq/testing';Sidekiq::Testing.inline!` to `sidekiq.rb`, it logs and raises an error as I expect though. Am I missing something?
Ruby 2.3.0
Rails 5.0.2
Sidekiq 4.2.9
Redis 3.2.0

sidekiq.rb

```
REDIS_URL  = 'localhost'
REDIS_PORT = '6379'
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{REDIS_URL}:#{REDIS_PORT}" }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: "redis://#{REDIS_URL}:#{REDIS_PORT}" }
end
```

indexable.rb

```
module Indexable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def index_elasticsearch
      Rails.logger.debug 'call'          
      Rails.logger.debug Indexer::Logger
      Rails.logger.debug Indexer::Client
      Rails.logger.debug self.id.to_s
      Indexer.perform_async(:index, self.id.to_s) # nothing happens here
      Rails.logger.debug 'after'         
      self
    end
  end

  class Indexer
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options queue: :elasticsearch, retry: false, backtrace: true

    Logger = Sidekiq.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG ? Sidekiq.logger : nil

    raise 'No config/elasticsearch.yml' unless File.exists? "config/elasticsearch.yml"
    erb    = ERB.new( File.read('config/elasticsearch.yml') ).result
    config = YAML.load(erb)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
    config.merge! logger: Logger

    Client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)

    def perform(operation, record_id)
      Rails.logger.debug [ operation, "ID: #{record_id}"]
      raise
    end
  end
end
```

some_mongoid_class.rb

```
class SomeMongoidClass
  ...
  include ::Indexable
  ...
  after_save :index_elasticsearch
end
```

console

```
bundle exec sidekiq -e development --queue elasticsearch --verbose

...Booting Sidekiq 4.2.9 with redis options {:url=>"redis://localhost:6379"}...
2017-11-10T ... DEBUG: {:queues=>["elasticsearch"], :labels=>[], :concurrency=>25, :require=>".", :environment=>"development", :timeout=>8, ...
```

rails console

```
SomeMongoidClass.create(...)

before
#<Logger:0x...
#<Elasticsearch::Transport::Client:0x...
BSON::ObjectId('...')
after
```

Comment: Are you using a unique job plugin?

Comment: @MikePerham Do you mean sidekiq-unique-jobs? No, I'm not using that plugin.

Comment: If you call `Sidekiq::Queue.new('elasticsearch').size` is the queue size increasing?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata No, it's not increasing.
`require 'sidekiq/api'`
=> true
`Sidekiq::Queue.all`
=> [#<Sidekiq::Queue:... @name="app", @rname="queue:app">,
 #<Sidekiq::Queue:... @name="elasticsearch", @rname="queue:elasticsearch">]
`Sidekiq::Queue.new('elasticsearch').size`
=> 0
`Sidekiq::Queue.new('elasticsearch').size`
=> 0
`Sidekiq::Queue.all`
=> [#<Sidekiq::Queue:... @name="app", @rname="queue:app">,
 #<Sidekiq::Queue:... @name="elasticsearch", @rname="queue:elasticsearch">]

Comment: Thank you. Can you check the return of the `Indexer.perform_async` method?

Comment: Using rspec-sidekiq? https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq#installation

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata No. Thank YOU. It returns some ID. I guess it's a job ID?[19] pry(main)> `Indexable::Indexer.perform_async`
=> "791209aae1285b13c5b46d27"

Comment: @MikePerham No, I'm not using rspec-sidekiq in any environment groups. I think using rspec-sidekiq is one of the most common cases where Sidekiq doesn't work as expected but it's not my case unfortunately, and that is why I am here. I'm feeling I'm missing something elementary though.

Comment: As it is returning the ID when calling`perform_async`... is it possible that you're enqueuing it in some other Redis installation? I mean, are you running your application and your Sidekiq instance pointing to the same Redis configuration?

Comment: @André Guimarães Sakata Redis says `The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379` and Sidekiq says `{:url=>"redis://localhost:6379"}` . But your comment rang a bell and I found out something else. When I checked running processes, 6 sidekiq extra processes(!) were running... I killed all of them, started a new sidekiq process and tried again but sill no luck :/ Thank you so much for your support anyway! I'll try to find out if I have anything else wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry but I'm running out of ideas right now... one thing you can do to better understand what is going on is to shutdown Sidekiq and run your application verifying through Sidekiq API (or directly in Redis) how the job is being enqueued. Good luck with that and feel free to put more updates here.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved as soon as I posted the last comment.

It was just a silly mistake. I didn't put the worker file into the workers folder of the app!